# how to add new rows on top after clearing rows in Android SQLite

Tags: android, database, sqlite

OK.there is the code for my class which exstends SQLiteOpenHelper.what this database keeps is not interesting.
the questions is:
for example I entere **10** rows in the table.
 after deleting all rows with the method

```
 public void removeQuestion(int id){
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            db.delete(TABLE_NAME, COL_ID + "=" + id, null);
        }
```

the database is cleared and I add new Row.
the problem is that the ID of row is 11,not 1.( as the table is cleaned,new row must be first row in the table).How can I control this?
this is the code:

```
public String ID = "id";
public String QUESTION = "question";
public string ANSWER = "answer ;     
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,QUESTION TEXT,ANSWER TEXT)");
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
            onCreate(db);
        }
        public void addQuestion(Question question){
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(COL_QUESTION, question.QUESTION);
            values.put(COL_V1, question.V1);
            values.put(ANSWER,question.ANSWER);
            // Inserting Row
            db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
            db.close(); // Closing database connection
        }
        public ArrayList<Question> getAllQuestions(){
            ArrayList<Question> questions = new ArrayList<Question>();
            String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    Question question = new Question();
                    question.ID = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0));
                    question.QUESTION= cursor.getString(1);                
                    question.ANSWER=cursor.getString(2);
                    questions.add(question);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            cursor.close();
            db.close();
            return questions;
        }
        public void removeQuestion(int id){
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            db.delete(TABLE_NAME, COL_ID + "=" + id, null);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

First check whether data is completely remove from your table or not then  that you just need to delete the sequences from your table inside question function like this

```
Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '" + TABLE_NAME + "'", null);
        if (cur != null) {
            if(cur.getCount()<=0)
            {
                db.execSQL("DELETE FROM SQLITE_SEQUENCE WHERE NAME = '" + TABLE_NAME + "'");
            }
        }
```

Comment: this would works.but what about the case when I dont delete the whole data? and delete only part of it.for example I delete 10th data so eleventh one should come to the position of ten.any solution for it?

Comment: In that case you should not use sequence. You should use assigned unique key as primary key.

Answer (score 1):

**Autoincrement** field **always increment** id.

If you delete all field and again insert data in that table it will increment your id not start from 1.

E.g If you insert 10 data and delete all data.

Now when you insert data then your Id will be 11 not 1.

**One solution** is that drop your table if there is no data exist.

Comment: yes.but for the case when there is 10 data and I delete one row,and the 11th row should became 10th.how to do this?